# how to execute innobackupex to be executed inside screen to transfer the data over the nc

Tags: gnu-screen, netcat, percona

I am using fabric tool  to automate database export and import. I am using innoabackupex tool to do the work. I have a requirement to start the backup inside a screen as the backup is very large size (above 300G). So its a must for me to send the data over nc to make it fast. So i am using below screen command which is not working while using pipe to send the data over nc

screen -fn -t test innobackupex  --stream=tar --tables-file=/backup/backup.txt  /data/backups/full-backup | nc target-server-ip 6789

Note:I have nc listening on my remote host to get the compressed data.

Please let me know the correct screen parameter to be used to execute the command opening a screen and to be run inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work this way:

```
screen -fn -t test /bin/bash -c "innobackupex --stream=tar \
  --tables-file=/backup/backup.txt /data/backups/full-backup \
| nc target-server-ip 6789"
```

Comment: I just happened to see this command is working on bash but not doing the same work when using inside fabric.

Comment: I haven't used Fabric yet so I can't offer any help on that.

Comment: I have removed the backslashes in fabfile. it worked for me..thanks bill. You answer helped me finish my automation work. cheers!

Comment: Oh really, the backslashes were the problem? Sorry, I put those in my answer above just so the code wouldn't make a horizontal scrollbar.